# How to set the glyph of a unicode character?

Tags: fonts, text-properties, display

I would like to set the glyph of a certain unicode character. Specifically, I would like the glyph § ([SECTION SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a7/index.htm)) to represent the unicode character U+202A ([LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embeddings)), a normally non-visible character, in the main buffer. However, this glyph assignment must be confined to the main buffer; in particular, it must not be used when printing the document as a PDF file.

Comment: Have a look at the manual on [text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html) and [overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html), which are alternate means to affect the printed representation on the screen without affecting the underlying content of the buffer/file.

Comment: "main buffer" has no meaning without context. With respect to importance, all emacs buffers are created equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is to set the display-table entry for character `LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING` to the glyph that is used for character `SECTION SIGN`.

```el
(aset (or (window-display-table)  standard-display-table)
      8234 ; 0x202A, which is the char LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
      (vector (make-glyph-code ?§)))
```

If the selected window has its own display table, then update that. If not, update the standard display table.

You can also put a face on that section-symbol glyph, if you like. For example:

```el
(aset (or (window-display-table)  standard-display-table)
      8234
      (vector (make-glyph-code ?§ 'escape-glyph)))
```

Comment: What is `standard-display-table` is `nil`?  Don't you need to create one?

Comment: @jch: Yes. The first arg to `aset` here should be a display table. You can use any display table you want - whatever is appropriate for your context. But yes, it needs to be a display table, not, e.g., `nil`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've ended up adding a slightly modified code to my .emacs file. I posted it in an answer to this thread.

Comment: What did you mean by 'you can also put a face on that section-symbol glyph'? What's a face? And what is the difference between this method and the first method described in your answer? Does the face argument always have to be `'escape-glyph`? If not - what other values can it take, and what does this value mean?

Comment: @EvanAad: See the Emacs and Elisp manuals, for what a face is. No, the face need not be face `escape-glyph` - see `C-h f make-glyph-code`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Drew's answer and to jch's comment, I've added the following lines to the beginning of my .emacs file.

```
(unless standard-display-table
    (setq standard-display-table (make-display-table))
)
(unless (aref standard-display-table #x202a)    (aset standard-display-table #x202a (vector (make-glyph-code #x22c9 'escape-glyph)))
)
(unless (aref standard-display-table #x202b)
    (aset standard-display-table #x202b (vector (make-glyph-code #x22ca 'escape-glyph)))
)
(unless (aref standard-display-table #x202c)
    (aset standard-display-table #x202c (vector (make-glyph-code #x22c8 'escape-glyph)))
)
```