# How to display Unicode bidi markers only in Whitespace mode?

Tags: whitespace-mode, bidirectional-support, buffer-display-table

[There's a way](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/6079/4084) of displaying Unicode bidirectionality markers. The problem is: it makes them visible all the time. Is it possible to show them only in `whitespace` mode?

PS I'm not chained to the method in the linked post. Any other way of displaying the Unicode bidi markers when in `whitespace` mode will be equally welcome.

Comment: This can be done with a display table I think. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html#Display-Tables

Comment: You can also check the variable whitespace-display-mappings