# How to switch off Unicode bidi markers?

Tags: unicode, bidirectional-support

Do you know how `whitespace` mode turns on the visibility of certain normally non-visible characters, such as the space and the tab? Well, I'd like to be able to emulate this with Unicode bidirectional characters (e.g. `Right-To-Left Mark` `U+200F`, `Pop Directional Isolate` `U+2069`).

One way to make, say, the Right-To-Left Mark visible, is to put the following lines in the `.emacs` file:

```
(unless standard-display-table
  (setq standard-display-table (make-display-table)))
(unless
  (aref standard-display-table #x200F) 
  (aset standard-display-table #x200F (vector (make-glyph-code #x22c9 'escape-glyph))))
```

The problem with this approach is that it keeps the mark visible all the time. I'd like a way to turn its visibility off, and then possibly on again later on.

---

This question is related to [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/how-to-display-unicode-bidi-markers-only-in-whitespace-mode?noredirect=1#comment52440_33854). The difference is that in the present question I'm not asking to turn the feature on only in `whitespace` mode, but rather to turn it off and on in the current mode, whatever it be. Hopefully this is an easier question to answer.